# Color the shaded area under the curve distribution plot different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using seaborn's kdeplot to draw the distribution of my data.

```
sns.kdeplot(data['numbers'], shade=True)
```

I want to divide the shaded area under the line into three parts, showing the "high" percentile and the "low" percentile. It would be ideal if I can color the shaded area with three different colors.

Any idea how I can go about doing that?

I want it to look something like the below where I can decide the cutoff value between the colors.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure seaborn has a direct command to fill a curve. But you can use matplotlib (if you have seaborn you also have matplotlib since its a dependency) to do this. Check [fill_between examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html).

Comment: @armatita I looked at fill_between already. Thing is this is a distribution, so it's like a historgram. The y is automatically generated. I just give it the x values. It doesn't have to be seaborn, generating something like this with matplotlib is also fine.

Comment: Its a very high level plot but its fully reproducible in matplolib. My guess is that seaborn [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) is using [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html). Its a bit more complex for sure but not that much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I figured out how to do it. I would retrieve and x and y arrays from the seaborn plot, then use `fill_between` to color under the curve.

```
points = sns.kdeplot(data['numbers'], shade=True).get_lines()[0].get_data()

x = points[0]
y = points[1]

plt.fill_between(x,y, where = x >=0.75, color='r')
plt.fill_between(x,y, where = x <=0.1, color='g')
plt.fill_between(x,y, where = (x<=0.75) & (x>=0.1), color='y')
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference since the original answer was posted is that `shade=True` needs to be changed to `shaded=False`.

I also just wanted to share a slightly more complete answer for those who want to copy-paste.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

mean = 0
std = 1

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=10000)

points = sns.kdeplot(x, shade=False, bw_method=1.0, color='black').get_lines()[0].get_data()

x = points[0]
y = points[1]

plt.fill_between(x, y, color='y')
plt.fill_between(x, y, where = (x<=0.5*std) & (x >= -0.5 * std), color='g') # 
plt.fill_between(x, y, where = (x>=2*std) | (x<=-2*std), color='r')
```

[image]